# Не могу создать правильный класс для серилизации Json

Tags: c#

После того как я написал код который работал правильно, выводил серилизованную строку в формате json, я сохранил его и добавил комментарии. После повторной компиляции программы код уже не работает. На выходе получаю строку:

```
[{}]
```

Должна быть:

```
[
  {
    "operationName": "ChannelPage_SetSessionStatus",
    "variables": {
      "input": {
        "sessionID": "fa073306f9e05288",
        "availability": "ONLINE",
        "activity": {
          "type": "WATCHING",
          "userID": "37402112",
          "gameID": null
        }
      }
    },
    "extensions": {
      "persistedQuery": {
        "version": 1,
        "sha256Hash": "8521e08af74c8cb5128e4bb99fa53b591391cb19492e65fb0489aeee2f96947f"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operationName": "ChannelPage_StreamType_User",
    "variables": {
      "channelLogin": "shroud"
    },
    "extensions": {
      "persistedQuery": {
        "version": 1,
        "sha256Hash": "43b152e4f17090ece0b50a5bc41e4690c7a6992ad3ed876d88bf7292be2d2cba"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Класс который серилизую:

```
public class TwitchStream
{
    internal class TwitchSetSessionStatus
    {
        public string operationName = "ChannelPage_SetSessionStatus"; // название метода
        internal class variables
        {
            internal class input
            {
                public string sessionID = "fa073306f9e05288"; // можно узнать из куков
                public string availability = "ONLINE"; // статус аккаунта онлайн, отошёл или невидимка
                internal class activity
                {
                    public string type = "WATCHING"; // что делаешь
                    public int userID = 37402112; // id стримера которого смотришь
                    public string gameID = null; // пока что не увидел что б она хоть где-то не null была
                }
            }
        }
        internal class extensions
        {
            internal class persistedQuery
            {
                public int version = 1; // версия Query, я так понял
                public string sha256Hash = "8521e08af74c8cb5128e4bb99fa53b591391cb19492e65fb0489aeee2f96947f"; // привязана к operationName
            }
        }
    }
    internal class TwitchStreamTypeUser
    {
        public string operationName = "ChannelPage_StreamType_User";
        internal class variables
        {
            public string channelLogin = "shroud"; // не изменяется на сервере, лучше писать правильное значение
        }
        internal class extensions
        {
            internal class persistedQuery
            {
                public int version = 1; // версия Query, я так понял
                public string sha256Hash = "43b152e4f17090ece0b50a5bc41e4690c7a6992ad3ed876d88bf7292be2d2cba"; // привязана к operationName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь класс выглядит так:

```
public class TwitchStreams
{
    public TwitchSetSessionStatus twitchSetSessionStatus = new TwitchSetSessionStatus();
    public TwitchStreamTypeUser twitchStreamTypeUser = new TwitchStreamTypeUser();

    public class TwitchSetSessionStatus
    {
        public string operationName = "ChannelPage_SetSessionStatus"; // название метода
        public Variables variables = new Variables();
        public Extensions extensions = new Extensions();
        public class Variables
        {
            public Input input = new Input();
            public class Input
            {
                public string sessionID = "fa073306f9e05288"; // можно узнать из куков
                public string availability = "ONLINE"; // статус аккаунта онлайн, отошёл или невидимка
                public Activity activity = new Activity();
                public class Activity
                {
                    public string type = "WATCHING"; // что делаешь
                    public int userID = 37402112; // id стримера которого смотришь
                    public string gameID = null; // пока что не увидел что б она хоть где-то не null была
                }
            }
        }
        public class Extensions
        {
            public PersistedQuery persistedQuery = new PersistedQuery();
            public class PersistedQuery
            {
                public int version = 1; // версия Query, я так понял
                public string sha256Hash = "8521e08af74c8cb5128e4bb99fa53b591391cb19492e65fb0489aeee2f96947f"; // привязана к operationName
            }
        }
    }
    public class TwitchStreamTypeUser
    {
        public string operationName = "ChannelPage_StreamType_User";
        public Variables variables = new Variables();
        public Extensions extensions = new Extensions();

        public class Variables
        {
            public string channelLogin = "shroud"; // не изменяется на сервере, лучше писать правильное значение
        }
        public class Extensions
        {
            public PersistedQuery persistedQuery = new PersistedQuery();

            public class PersistedQuery
            {
                public int version = 1; // версия Query, я так понял
                public string sha256Hash = "43b152e4f17090ece0b50a5bc41e4690c7a6992ad3ed876d88bf7292be2d2cba"; // привязана к operationName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И Json так:

```
[
  {
    "twitchSetSessionStatus": {
      "operationName": "ChannelPage_SetSessionStatus",
      "variables": {
        "input": {
          "sessionID": "fa073306f9e05288",
          "availability": "ONLINE",
          "activity": {
            "type": "121",
            "userID": 37402112,
            "gameID": null
          }
        }
      },
      "extensions": {
        "persistedQuery": {
          "version": 1,
          "sha256Hash": "8521e08af74c8cb5128e4bb99fa53b591391cb19492e65fb0489aeee2f96947f"
        }
      }
    },
    "twitchStreamTypeUser": {
      "operationName": "ChannelPage_StreamType_User",
      "variables": {
        "channelLogin": "shroud"
      },
      "extensions": {
        "persistedQuery": {
          "version": 1,
          "sha256Hash": "43b152e4f17090ece0b50a5bc41e4690c7a6992ad3ed876d88bf7292be2d2cba"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Как мне убрать название переменных на 3-ий и 23-ий строке?

Comment: Вы поудаляли все свойства из Ваших классов. Вот ничего и не сериализуется.

Comment: я специально удалил что бы не палить данные, обычно там все данные находятся во всех полях

Comment: А такая структура разве вообще должна работать? Попробуйте инициализируйте где нибудь, напишите `var data = new Stream();` и через `data.` достаньте к примеру `operationName`, получится? Нет, потому что у вас все классы пустые, в них нету данных с которыми можно работать. И я тут без понятия как вы получили нормальный JSON.

Comment: Не торопитесь ). Прочитайте внимательно мой комментарий. Подумайте. Я имею ввиду не *значения* свойств, а *декларации* свойств.

Comment: Изменил код и выходной json на те который у меня со всеми данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще раз. Не в значениях, которые Вы добавили в код вопроса, дело.

Давайте разберемся. Возьмем класс `TwitchStreamTypeUser`. У объекта этого типа есть поле `operationName`, и больше ничего.

```
internal class TwitchStreamTypeUser
{
    public string operationName = "ChannelPage_StreamType_User";
    internal class variables
    {
        public string channelLogin = "shroud"; // не изменяется на сервере, лучше писать правильное значение
    }
    internal class extensions
    {
        internal class persistedQuery
        {
            public int version = 1; // версия Query, я так понял
            public string sha256Hash = "43b152e4f17090ece0b50a5bc41e4690c7a6992ad3ed876d88bf7292be2d2cba"; // привязана к operationName
        }
    }
}
```

Да, внутри него есть два другие типа/класса, но полей/свойств такого типа у `TwitchStreamTypeUser` нет.

Измените класс `TwitchStreamTypeUser`:

```
internal class TwitchStreamTypeUser
{
    public string operationName = "ChannelPage_StreamType_User";
    public variables variables = new variables();
    public extensions extensions = new extensions();

    internal class variables
    {
        public string channelLogin = "shroud"; // не изменяется на сервере, лучше писать правильное значение
    }
    internal class extensions
    {
        public persistedQuery persistedQuery = new persistedQuery();

        internal class persistedQuery
        {
            public int version = 1; // версия Query, я так понял
            public string sha256Hash = "43b152e4f17090ece0b50a5bc41e4690c7a6992ad3ed876d88bf7292be2d2cba"; // привязана к operationName
        }
    }
}
```

И аналогично, остальные классы.

---

> Как мне убрать название переменных на 3-ий и 23-ий строке?

Мы идем вперед семимильными шагами ).

Кроме названий придется убрать и лишние фигурные скобки.

Поместите эти два объекта в массив `object[]` или список `List<object>` и сериализуйте этот контейнер.

Comment: 1. Я понял что не инициализировал класс
2. Как мне серилизовать данные что бы они были в нужном ввиде? У мня они получались с названиями переменных, а нужны без них.

Comment: @ЯрославXaray То есть, Вам все понятно?

Comment: Не, мне второе не понятно, думал на Enter перенос строки.

Comment: @ЯрославXaray Как это - "без названий переменных" (Вы, наверное, имеете ввиду названия полей и свойств)?  Пример JSON-а в вопросе это то, что Вам нужно?

Comment: Я серилизую массив класса. В этом массиве будут одинаковые классы, а мне нужны классы в которых будут разные типы переменных, но запись должна идти как при массиве.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы серилизация вышла в точно такой же вид как json.

Comment: Добавил изменённые данные классов и серилизованые в json данные. Переменные на 3-ий и 23-ий строке не должны быть, а они есть, как от них избавиться?

Comment: Переместил классы из TwitchStream, а его удалил.Через object[] всё работает как надо.

Comment: @ЯрославXaray Молодец! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.